# AngularJS material push element to the right of the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to push / float a drop-down to the right with no success, tried also to apply `float: right;` on `md-input-container`:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="right">
    <div class="md-select-sort">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Sort By</label>
            <md-select ng-model="sort">
                <md-optgroup label="Sort By">
                    <md-option value="DateLastModified">Date Last Modified (Asc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="-DateLastModified">Date Last Modified (Desc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="DateCreated">Date Created (Asc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="-DateCreated">Date Created (Desc)</md-option>
                </md-optgroup>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a specifiec way to accomplish that? Why just `float: right` don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `layout-align="end center"` and you will be fine like in this [demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Njw63VKoUyD8RBaa5H2X?p=preview).

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <div class="md-select-sort">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Sort By</label>
            <md-select ng-model="sort">
                <md-optgroup label="Sort By">
                    <md-option value="DateLastModified">Date Last Modified (Asc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="-DateLastModified">Date Last Modified (Desc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="DateCreated">Date Created (Asc)</md-option>
                    <md-option value="-DateCreated">Date Created (Desc)</md-option>
                </md-optgroup>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help ya